# php mysql- put mysql_fetch_array() result in to a string and split the string by comma

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have a mysql table(request) here:

```
request:
r_id     item_no
  1         1
  13        10
  22        20
  33        30 
  55        40
```

Now, I'm using php to take r_id out using `mysql_fetch_array()` and try to put `mysql_fetch_array()` result in to a string also split the string by comma.

```
<?php   
include('config.php'); //connect to mysql
function f(){
    $sql = "SELECT r_id FROM `request` ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $string = '';
    $i = 0; 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $string .= $row[$i];
    }
    $newstring = implode(", ", preg_split("/[\0-9]+/", $string));
    return  $newstring ;
}

$get=f();
echo $get;
?>
```

But I cannot get the right string form my php code.

I want to get the string like

```
1,13,22,33,55
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: what you are getting??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to split that and implode, just do this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $string .= $row[$i].',';// append comma after each value you append to the string
}
return substr($string,0,-1);// cut off the trailing comma from the final string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my updated answer:

```
$sql = "SELECT r_id FROM `request` ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$string = '';
$i = 0; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $string .= $row[$i].",";
}
return  $string ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
include('config.php'); //connect to mysql
function f(){
    $sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(r_ID) FROM `request` ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    return  $result ;
}

$get=f();
echo $get;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
while(...){
   $array = $row[$i]; //first you need array 
}
$string = implode(",",$array); //now you have your string
```

Comment: always follow the stackover flow standards for giving the answer